# Connection pooling - what gives?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Ok, I have a web app on AWS that is using load balancing and autoscaling over two regions. When i check my connections, it seems as if connection pooling is not being used? Or is it just me that doesn't understand it properly? I have attached an image, and I have the following questions:

[image: Pooling]

Just FYI: The colors indicated the same numbers, so the yellow ones are the same IP and so on. Just wanted to blur them, because who knows, right?

Also: the green connections comes from my computer, that is me using Workbench. The red/yellow I assume are my two servers, and the blue I am not sure. Will check these IPs.

1) Why does the bottom red connection and bottom yellow have a connection each? its the same IP, with the same user, calling the same DB.

2) Why are ports being added to the host IP? Is this what is causing new connections to spawn?

3) The two top green connections are also not sharing the same connection? Why two separate ones?

4) Why is the Id (purple outline) same for all connections?

Comment: Where is that table from or how have you generated it?

Comment: @Progman workbench, checking Connections